# Модифицированный Histogram

Tags: python

Помогите решить задачу. Результатом будет статистика для сигнала, которую он генерирует следующим образом:

1. функция сначала очищает сигнал всех отсчетов с амплитудой больше ‹max_amplitude› и меньше ‹min_amplitude›,
2. впоследствии повторно дискретизируйте его, объединяя каждый образец ‹bucket› (последний образец может быть неполным) в один, вычисляя их диаметр и затем округляя его (используя встроенную функцию ‹round›),
3. наконец, он подсчитывает, сколько раз отдельные амплитуды появляются в модифицированном сигнале, и возвращает словарь, где ключом будет амплитуда, а значением будет количество его появлений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку это явно учебная задачка, кода не будет, но будут подсказки. Вообще, у вас всё расписано по пунктам уже, только код написать осталось:

1. Тут нужно отфильтровать данные по условию. Проще всего это сделать с помощью **списочного сокращения** с условием `if` внутри, это одна простая строчка кода.
2. Тут прямо написано, что нужно что-то округлить с помощью `round`, но не совсем понятно, что именно. В общем, нужно разбить список на куски по `bucket` элементов в каждом из кусков, посчитать по этому куску **среднее арифметическое**, ну и округлить его. Это тоже можно сделать с помощью **списочного сокращения**, плюс использовать для получения индексов `range(len(data))`, но немного модифицированный - с шагом `bucket`. Также вам пригодятся **срезы** по списку. Опять же можно в одну строку это сделать.
3. Считать элементы в списке умеет `functools.Counter`, но вам наверняка нельзя его использовать. Аналог счётчика легко пишется через словарь, можно использовать метод `.get` словаря с дефолтным значением, чтобы чуть сократить код. Но если хотите написать опять же в одну строку код, то можно использовать метод списка `count`, **словарное сокращение** и не забыть, что в качестве ключа словаря элементы должны браться уникальные, а значит пригодится **множество**.

Код будет гораздо короче моего описания, но, повторюсь, учебное задание вы должны написать сами, в этом его смысл.

Я то код написал и он проходит все тесты. И он достаточно короткий и простой, только п.2 чуть более длинной строкой делается.